# getting a deeply nested css element with jquery

Tags: jquery, nested, css-selectors

I'm having troubles running an `onchange` event on a somewhat deeply nested form pulldown.

So basically I have a form with an id of `maxResultsForm` inside a table with an id of `listProductsResults` inside another table with an id of `listProductsSettings`... with an id on the `select` tag of `maxResults`

I've tried the below selector and many variations without  any success on it triggering.

```
$("form#maxResultsForm table#listProductsResults td table#listProductsSettings td :select#maxResults").change(function()...
```

anyone see what I'm doing wrong?
thanks in advance!

j

Comment: http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/

Comment: This construct insinuates that you're using the **same** ID on *multiple* elements. Ensure that this is *not* the case. Otherwise it would just have been `$(#maxselects)`.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the id just do `$('#maxResults').change(...)`.

Comment: If it has an id, it must be unique and the id-based selector is the best way to find it.

Comment: well i do have a  unique id on the selec tagt and $('#maxResults').change(...) still doesn't trigger for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form#maxResultsForm select#maxResults").change(function()...
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re getting your CSS selectors backwards. If you had “a form with an id of `maxResultsForm` inside a table with an id of `listProductsResults`” then your selector would look like this:

```
table#listProductsResults form#maxResultsForm
```

However, as the other answers mentioned, you can’t have two HTML elements on a page with the same value for their ID attribute, as IDs have to be unique. So, if your `<select>` tag has an ID attribute, you only need to use that to select it.

```
$('#maxResults').change(function(){...});
```